# How to configure Jenkins to detect SVN changes and execute a job?

Tags: c++, linux, svn, jenkins, cmake

I have configured [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65143593) and created a job to checkout, build and run a simple project from SVN. I could configure this job to run periodically, like once every five minutes. But I'd like it to build the project only when something has changed on the SVN repository. I read the "**Builds by source changes**" section of [this document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-Buildsbysourcechanges), but could not figure out what exactly I am meant to do! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configure your job you have to do this:

1. In the **Source Code Management** specify the source management system you use (for instance SVN) and fill all required fields (url, authentication, ...) (probably already done since you are able to do a checkout)
2. in the **Build Triggers** section : choose Poll SCM with a schedule `*/10 * * * *` for checking the repository every 10 minutes.

Comment: What's the meaning of `10 * * * *`. Does it mean once every 10 minutes too?

Comment: `10 * * * * * ` means at the tenth minute of every hour

Comment: H/10 * * * *    
better, as someone explains here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383778/spread-load-evenly-by-using-h-rather-than-5

Answer (score 1):

Go to the configuration of your project and scroll down to the **Build Triggers** directly under the **Source Code Management** section. Here you've to configure it this way:

[image]

The syntax to schedule the job is in the **crontab format** take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Predefined_scheduling_definitions).

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is Subversion post commit hook that will execute what ever you script in your hook script. Take a look at the following example by Mike West:

[Mike West - Subversion Post-commit-hook](https://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101)

good luck!