# Spread load evenly by using ‘H * * * *’ rather than ‘5 * * * *’

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration

When setting up how Jenkins shoul pull changes from subversion
I tried checked Poll SCM and set schedule to `5 * * * *`, I get the following warning

> Spread load evenly by using ‘H * * * *’ rather than ‘5 * * * *’

I'm not sure what H means in this context and why I should use that.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

H stands for Hash

> To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the
>   system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used wherever possible.
>   For example, using 0 0 * * * for a dozen daily jobs will cause a large
>   spike at midnight. In contrast, using H H * * * would still execute
>   each job once a day, but not all at the same time, better using
>   limited resources.

Comment: Nicely explained by @CédricJulien here too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12472740/1579667

Comment: It should allow you set a window (no earlier than this, no later than this). If you set an exact time, it should run it at the exact time.

Comment: @AlexanderMills it does: The H symbol can be used with a range. For example, H H(0-7) * * * means some time between 12:00 AM (midnight) to 7:59 AM. You can also use step intervals with H, with or without ranges.

Comment: So symbol H is like a random integer?I don't really know about the meaning of "hash",too.

Answer (score 33):

Click on the question-mark beside your schedule specification.
It says there:

> To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the
>   system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used wherever possible.
>   For example, using 0 0 * * * for a dozen daily jobs will cause a large
>   spike at midnight. In contrast, using H H * * * would still execute
>   each job once a day, but not all at the same time, better using
>   limited resources.

Answer (score 21):

Also in the documentation worth noting is that:

The H symbol can be used with a range. For example, H H(0-7) * * * means some time between 12:00 AM (midnight) to 7:59 AM. You can also use step intervals with H, with or without ranges.

The H symbol can be thought of as a random value over a range, but it actually is a hash of the job name, not a random function, so that the value remains stable for any given project.