# Jenkins build scheduler?

Tags: jenkins, cron

I am doing continuous integration with Jenkins. And I want my project to be built everyday at midnight. I used the cron H H * * * but it is not on mid-night. Also I'm having a warning when i set it to 0 0 * * *.
[image]

[image]

My Question:

1. what is the difference between "H H * * *" and "0 0 * * *"
2. How can I set the build schedule to mid-night(everyday).

Comment: and I'm new to Jenkins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1st question, answer is you may ignore the warning. "H H * * *" is for periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the system and "0 0 " " "" means scheduled the task at fixed time and only once.
You may look at "[Spread load evenly by using ‘H * * * *’ rather than ‘5 * * * *’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383778/spread-load-evenly-by-using-h-rather-than-5)"

For 2nd point, "0 0 * * *" seems correct way. Please check if it is related to timezone difference of your system and server.

Regards,
Krish